# Extracting a number following specific text in R

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I have a data frame which contains a column full of text. I need to capture the number (can potentially be any number of digits from most likely 1 to 4 digits in length) that follows a certain phrase, namely **'Floor Area'** or **'floor area'**. My data will look something like the following:

```
"A beautiful flat on the 3rd floor with floor area: 50 sqm and a lift"
"Newbuild flat. Floor Area: 30 sq.m" 
"6 bed house with floor area 50 sqm, lot area 25 sqm"
```

If I try to extract just the number or if I look back from sqm I will sometimes get the lot area by mistake.If someone could help me with a lookahead regex or similar in stringr, I'd appreciate it. Regex is a weak point for me. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**A common technique to extract a number before or after a word** is to match all the string up to the word or number or number and word while capturing the number and then matching the rest of the string and replacing with the captured substring using `sub`:

```
# Extract the first number after a word:
as.integer(sub(".*?<WORD_OR_PATTERN_HERE>.*?(\\d+).*", "\\1", x))

# Extract the first number after a word:
as.integer(sub(".*?(\\d+)\\s*<WORD_OR_PATTERN_HERE>.*", "\\1", x))
```

**NOTE**: Replace `\\d+` with `\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?` to match int or float numbers (to keep consistency with the code above, remember change `as.integer` to `as.numeric`). `\\s*` matches 0 or more whitespace in the second `sub`.

**For the current scenario**, a possible solution will look like

```
v <- c("A beautiful flat on the 3rd floor with floor area: 50 sqm and a lift","Newbuild flat. Floor Area: 30 sq.m","6 bed house with floor area 50 sqm, lot area 25 sqm")
as.integer(sub("(?i).*?\\bfloor area:?\\s*(\\d+).*", "\\1", v))
# [1] 50 30 50
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/6gVIQt/1).

You may also leverage a capturing mechanism with `str_match` from *stringr* and get the second column value (`[,2]`):

```
> library(stringr)
> v <- c("A beautiful flat on the 3rd floor with floor area: 50 sqm and a lift","Newbuild flat. Floor Area: 30 sq.m","6 bed house with floor area 50 sqm, lot area 25 sqm")
> as.integer(str_match(v, "(?i)\\bfloor area:?\\s*(\\d+)")[,2])
[1] 50 30 50
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6gVIQt/3).

The regex matches:

- `(?i)` - in a case-insensitive way
- `\\bfloor area:?` - a whole word (`\b` is a word boundary) `floor area` followed by an optional `:` (one or zero occurrence, `?`)
- `\\s*` - zero or more whitespace
- `(\\d+)` - Group 1 (will be in `[,2]`) capturing one or more digits

See [R demo online](https://rextester.com/ZDFMK57501)

Comment: This is great. Many thanks, and thanks for the kind, detailed explanations!

Comment: To capture decimals numbers  can replace `(\\d+)` with `(\\d+(?:.\\d+))`, just remember to also change `as.integer`, to `as.numeric`.

Answer (score 0):

You need lookbehind regex.

```
str_extract_all(x, "\\b[Ff]loor [Aa]rea:?\\s*\\K\\d+", perl=T)
```

or

```
str_extract_all(x, "(?i)\\bfloor area:?\\s*\\K\\d+", perl=T)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lP4mZ8/1)

Donno why the above code won't return anything. You may try `sub` also,

```
> sub(".*\\b[Ff]loor\\s+[Aa]rea:?\\s*(\\d+).*", "\\1", x)
[1] "50" "30" "50"
```

Comment: `perl` is not an argument to `str_extract_all()`

Comment: so, no need for perl arg in st_extract_all?

Comment: for 'perl=TRUE' says 'unused argument' and without using perl it just shows 'character(0)'

Comment: @AvinashRaj: The latest versions of `stringr` uses **ICU** regex library. :) It does not support `\K`.

Comment: Who did that? Going to slap the developer of stringr package with rotten fish.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex may get you started:

```
[Ff]loor\s+[Aa]rea:?\s+(\d{1,4})
```

[The DEMO.](https://regex101.com/r/oX5dO2/1)

Answer (score 0):

use following regex with Case Insensitive matching:

```
floor\s*area:?\s*(\d{1,4})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text<- "A beautiful flat on the 3rd floor with floor area: 50 sqm and a lift"

unique(na.omit(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(unlist(text), "[^0-9]+")))))
# [1]  3 50
```

Hope this helped.